# Find the power series about $x_0 = 0$ and the radius of convergence of the following function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Find the power series about $x_0 = 0$ and the radius of convergence of the following function:
$$\frac{1}{1-x}$$

The power series of the function is $$\sum_{n=0}^∞(x^n)$$ and the interval of the convergence is $$-1<x<1$$
The radius of convergence is $1/2$ the interval so $R=1$.

How do I find the power series about $x_0 = 0$?

Comment: You asked this same question yesterday. The power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ is the same that the Taylor series of $\frac1{1-x}$ around $x_0=0$. Check it.

Comment: You just did.  A power series centered at $x_0$ an expression of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n (x-x_0)^n$.  If $x_0 = 0$, the series takes the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$.

Comment: It is a geometric series with radius $r=x$

Comment: You are mixing up some terminology. You don't have power series about a point, you have Taylor expansions about a point. 

Power series can be any series of the form $\sum C_n x^n$. Taylor series are a specific KIND of power series, where for a specific function $f(x)$ and a specific center $x_0$ we have $C_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}$ for every $n$.